# How to estimate how many cpus usually is allocated for Aurora Serveless (RDS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I need to migrate from Aurora RDS back to on-premises (MySQL 8). As it is Serveless, is there a way to I determine how much CPU I will need in the virtual machine in the on-premises environment?

My Aurora RDS is

> Instance type: Serverless v2,
> Minimum capacity: 1 ACUs (2 GiB),
> Maximum capacity: 10 ACUs (20 GiB)

I've looked for something in CloudWatch, but I am not sure how much amount of CPU to estimate. It only shows the percent of CPU being used at the moment.

[image]

[image]